# sqlite get current date as integer yyyyMMdd

Tags: sqlite, date, integer, format

is there any way to get the current date as an integer, in format yyyyMMdd ?

Already tried :

```
select date ('now')
```

But the result is 2015-06-12

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(strftime('%Y%m%d', 'now') AS int);
```

[Date And Time Functions](http://sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)